Ubuntu 22.04 ppc64 RMC inactive
I installed a new partition in PowerVM with Ubuntu 22.04, but the RMC connection with HMC stills inactive and cannot use the dynamic partitioning utilities.  When I try to stop the service ctrmc, the server responds that exists a socket problem.
